# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener - Swipebox Mobie

Tags: javascript, slideshow, swipe, preventdefault

I'm using Swipebox : http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/
I know that I can open a  content with swipebox slide like that

```
// Link to click
<a href="#mydiv" class="my-swipebox">Click to show</a>

// And the div in html
<div id="#mydiv">Click <a href="http://example.com">Here</div>
```

The problem is I can't click the link inside this div when it opened by swipebox on mobie (on desktop it working very fine)

The chrome browser show this log :

```
[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080
preventDefault @ js_3q9o_g1v9VMwOb38KwiIL35eXGTsWaJ31hpdemJVNbY.js:5
dispatch @ js_3q9o_g1v9VMwOb38KwiIL35eXGTsWaJ31hpdemJVNbY.js:5
v.handle @ js_3q9o_g1v9VMwOb38KwiIL35eXGTsWaJ31hpdemJVNbY.js:5
```

How can I fix this problem, thank you so much

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript along with your question please.

Comment: Hello @KristianRoebuck, you can download code at the bottom of this page, http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/, and you can put my code inside index.html, make swipe call (javascript) by $(".my-swipebox").swipebox(). THanks

Answer (score 1):

A passive event listener is an event where you promise the browser that you will never invoke event.preventDefault(). That way the browser can optimize actions like scrolling/touches because the browser can assume the developer will not be cancelled out (e.g. disabling scrolling).

Chrome enables this by default as per version 56: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080. They made this change as a way to optimize scrolling.

If you do not want to this to happen, you can add { passive: false } as the third argument to `.addEventListener`.

Read more about passive events at: https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md

Answer (score 0):

I added `loop: true` in .js
for this :
`$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({`
and it's work

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to explain a little bit your answer. Even if it is working, it is not clear what should be done.

Comment: in my case , my js is here:    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        rtl: true,
      // loop: true,
//        dots: true,
       autoWidth: true,
        margin: 13,
        
        responsive: {//for count of item for show
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            480: {
                items: 2
            },
            768: {
                items: 5
            },
            100: {
                items: 10
            }
        }
    }); i uncommented loop:true , and this error be ok

Comment: So, please, add this information to your answer and you will be upvoted. Great!