# Preventing the default for a passive default

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to prevent the default scrolling behavior.

Initially I tried this, from [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314377/event-preventdefault-not-stopping-mousewheel-in-firefox) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

```
$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', wheel);

function wheel(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
}
```

This resulted in this error: 
`[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See <URL>`

Sure. I found [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101723/unable-to-preventdefault-inside-passive-event-listener) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45120638/unable-to-preventdefault-inside-passive-event-listener-swipebox-mobie) and added their solution.

```
$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', wheel, {passive:false});
```

Now however I am getting the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: ((p.event.special[l.origType] || {}).handle || l.handler).apply is not a function
    at dispatch (0dfbbab736b8.js:formatted:1850)
    at h (0dfbbab736b8.js:formatted:1685)`

[The only related question I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231036/uncaught-typeerror-x-event-speciali-origtype-intermediate-value-handl) simply told me to remove the `{passive:false}`, which means I'm back at my original problem.

What am I doing wrong? How can I prevent the default behavior here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an obscure jQuery error - why not just ditch the jQuery and use the built-in event instead?

```js
window.addEventListener('wheel', e => e.preventDefault(), { passive: false });
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
```